# sed replace text between comma

Tags: awk, sed, replace

I have csv files that need to be changed f -> 0 and t -> 1 only between commas for every single csv if it matches. From:

```
,t,t,f,f,a,t,f,t,f,f,t,f,
tftf
```

to:

```
,1,1,0,0,a,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,
tftf
```

Works this way, but want to know better way that could reduce the replacing time consume

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
  echo "converting tables for mariaDB"
  find ./ -type f -name "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\,t\,/\,1\,/g'
  find ./ -type f -name "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\,f\,/\,0\,/g'
  echo "$i time(s) changed "
done
```

I except , one single command will change the line

Comment: not sure why you are using for loop here.. you don't need to escape `,` in sed command and you can use multiple commands at the same time... and you do not need xargs... try `find ./ -type f -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i 's/,t,/,1,/g; s/,f,/,0,/g' {} +` use `\;` if your `find` doesn't support `+`

Comment: I suggest with `sed` two loops: `':1;s/,t,/,1,/g;t1; :2;s/,f,/,0,/g;t2'`

Comment: @Cyrus oh I get it now why OP had used loops.. great observation

Comment: can use `perl` here ... `perl -i -pe 's/,\Kt(?=,)/1/g; s/,\Kf(?=,)/0/g'`

Comment: To be sure, only between commas? What about lines like this: `t,t,f` ?

Comment: @Gil, Could you please check my solutions if those help you too?

Comment: Why are 6 loops made? Are two not enough in the example of the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Though it is not perfect solution but would be simplest use it in case you don't have `gawk`'s latest version where `-inplace` edit option is present.

```
for file in *.csv
  awk '{gsub(/,t,/,",1,");gsub(/,f,/,",0,");gsub(/,t,/,",1,");gsub(/,f,/,",0,")} 1' "$file" > temp && mv temp"$file"
done
```

OR

```
for file in *.csv
    awk -v t_val="1" -v f_val="0" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=2;i<NF;i++){$i=($i=="t"?t_val:$i=="f"?f_val:$i)}} 1' "$file" > temp && mv temp "$file"
done
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `gawk`'s latest version where we could save edit into Input_file itself.

```
gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/,t,/,",1,");gsub(/,f,/,",0,");gsub(/,t,/,",1,");gsub(/,f,/,",0,")} 1' *.csv
```

OR

```
gawk -i inplace -v t_val="1" -v f_val="0" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=2;i<NF;i++){$i=($i=="t"?t_val:$i=="f"?f_val:$i)}} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: The problem you have here is that a line looking like `,t,t,t,t,` will not have all the `t`'s converted. `gsub` does not do overlap.

Comment: @kvantour, Thanks a TON for letting me know, I only tested it with given samples by OP(didn't assume anything). I have come up with a solution of double `gsub` using as of now, thinking more if I could get it done in a single shot too, your views are always welcome sir, cheers.

Comment: Why not something like `BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } { for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) $i = ($i == "t" ? 1 : $i == "f" ? 0 : $i) } 1`? I mean this is more awkish and faster than answers given so far except for sed w two loops

Comment: @oguzismail I had that one written down in my first answer. This works nice, but is slow if you have a lot of fields. The reason it is slow is that you redefine a field every time and as a consequence, you recompute `$0` and split it again in fields over and over and over. A quicker way is to store `$0` in `tmp`. Use `split`,  process the array and rebuild the array with `printf`. However, I always found it a pitty that `awk` does not have a `merge` command which does the opposite of `split`.

Comment: @kvantour, Thanks sir for sharing your thoughts, wouldn't be then 2 `gsub` will be FASTER than looping than :) :) What you say sir?

Comment: @oguzismail, Thanks buddy I have added that solution in OR post of mine solution, kindly do let me know in case of any suggestions or edit please.

Comment: The double `gsub` is clearly faster. I presented an update to the 'field' update which would avoid the recomputation of `$0` and the automatic "field splitting"

Comment: @kvantour *slow if you have a lot of fields* you're right, I didn't think about that. But still I like the sed with two loops better

Answer (score 1):

The main problem, in this case, is that a regular expression does not allow overlap when parsing it with `sed 's/ere/str/g'` or `awk '{gsub(ere,str,$0)}'`. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534256/sed-replace-text-between-comma#comment103392003_58534256) nicely explains how you can circumvent this in `sed` using the `t<label>` command, which means: *if a change happened to the pattern space, move to <label>.* The comment shows a generic way of doing it. The awk alternative to this rule would be:

```
$ awk '{while(match($0,ere)) gsub(ere,str)}'
```

An alternative `sed` solution in the case of the OP's example could use the following idea:

1. duplicate all commas. Since we are searching for strings of the form ",t,", this duplication avoid overlap using `s`.
2. since no overlap is possible, replace all ",f," with ",0," and all ",t," with ",1,".
3. We can now revert all duplicated commas again. As no overlap is allowed, sequences like `,,,,` will be nicely converted to `,,` and not `,`

In POSIX sed this looks like:

```
$ sed -e 's/,/,,/g' -e 's/,f,/,0,/g' \
      -e 's/,t,/,1,/g' -e 's/,,/,/g' file > file.tmp
$ mv file.tmp file
```

With GNU sed we can do it in one go:

```
$ sed -i 's/,/,,/g;s/,f,/,0,/g;s/,t,/,1,/g;s/,,/,/g' file
```

With awk, this would look like:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=FS FS}
       {$1=$1;gsub(/,f,/,",0,");gsub(/,t,/,",1,");gsub(OFS,FS)}1' file > file.tmp
$ mv file.tmp file
```